# CSS Table TR Background color issue

Tags: css, colors, background, css-tables

Here is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/teo7auv3/

What I am trying to do is when the validation returns errors, I want to set the background color to red on my whole TR. The issue is probably within this:

```
.ui-table tr:nth-child(even) {background: #fff}
.ui-table tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #f2ebde}
```

Because if I remove that, it works. However, I do wish to use that for alternating row colors. Any ideas?

Comment: Not a snarky comment but you just had to look at the selector for `ui-table-highlight` :)

Comment: Hahahahaha yeah sometimes that works.. :)

Comment: if you set background property inline it will override other properties..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a more specific selector for your error color rule :

```
.ui-table tr.ui-table-error {
    background-color:#ffebef;
}
```

If you don’t know yet, what specificity in CSS means, read f.e. http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: Thanks, it seems I was looking in the wrong place :)